# Number of process ID

Tags: process

why number of my process id reach to 32433 ?

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
1 ?        00:00:01 init
2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
3 ?        00:00:45 ksoftirqd/0
5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H
8 ?        00:00:02 migration/0
9 ?        00:00:00 rcu_bh
10 ?        00:01:12 rcu_sched
11 ?        00:00:01 watchdog/0
12 ?        00:00:01 watchdog/1
13 ?        00:00:03 migration/1
14 ?        00:00:47 ksoftirqd/1
16 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:0H
17 ?        00:00:00 khelper
18 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
19 ?        00:00:00 netns
20 ?        00:00:00 bdi-default
21 ?        00:00:00 kintegrityd
22 ?        00:00:00 kblockd
24 ?        00:00:00 ata_sff
25 ?        00:00:00 khubd
26 ?        00:00:00 md
27 ?        00:00:00 devfreq_wq
29 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
30 ?        00:00:50 kswapd0
31 ?        00:00:00 ksmd
32 ?        00:00:00 khugepaged
33 ?        00:00:00 fsnotify_mark
34 ?        00:00:00 ecryptfs-kthrea
35 ?        00:00:00 crypto
46 ?        00:00:00 kthrotld
50 ?        00:00:00 binder
69 ?        00:00:00 deferwq
70 ?        00:00:00 charger_manager
251 ?        00:00:00 firewire
261 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
262 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_1
263 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_2
264 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_3
330 ?        00:00:08 jbd2/sda1-8                                                                                                                                                                                                          
331 ?        00:00:00 ext4-dio-unwrit                                                                                                                                                                                                      
334 ?        00:00:02 kworker/0:1H                                                                                                                                                                                                         
339 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:1H                                                                                                                                                                                                         
418 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-br                                                                                                                                                                                                      
420 ?        00:00:00 udevd                                                                                                                                                                                                                
659 ?        00:00:20 kworker/0:0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
719 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u:0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
722 ?        00:00:00 irq/47-mei                                                                                                                                                                                                           
727 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u:2                                                                                                                                                                                                          
732 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
733 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u:1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
734 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:2                                                                                                                                                                                                          
736 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u:3                                                                                                                                                                                                          
758 ?        00:00:00 konsole                                                                                                                                                                                                              
761 pts/2    00:00:00 bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
774 ?        00:00:00 kmemstick                                                                                                                                                                                                            
775 ?        00:00:00 kpsmoused                                                                                                                                                                                                            
778 ?        00:00:00 cfg80211                                                                                                                                                                                                             
785 ?        00:00:00 pccardd
787 ?        00:00:00 r592_io
794 ?        00:00:00 kvm-irqfd-clean
797 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u:1H
801 ?        00:00:00 r852
813 ?        00:16:01 irq/48-iwlwifi
823 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
825 ?        00:00:00 ktpacpid
846 ?        00:00:00 hd-audio0
860 ?        00:00:00 iwlwifi
883 ?        00:00:19 rsyslogd
888 ?        00:00:08 flush-8:0
916 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-
1010 ?        00:00:27 dbus-daemon
1031 ?        00:00:00 modem-manager
1054 ?        00:00:02 cupsd
1063 ?        00:00:00 bluetoothd
1067 tty4     00:00:00 getty
1078 tty5     00:00:00 getty
1079 ?        00:00:00 krfcommd
1092 tty2     00:00:00 getty
1093 tty3     00:00:00 getty
1094 ?        00:00:00 kdm
1096 tty6     00:00:00 getty
1104 ?        00:00:00 acpid
1106 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
1107 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
1109 ?        00:00:00 cron
1110 ?        00:00:00 atd
1119 ?        00:00:36 irqbalance
1174 ?        00:00:25 NetworkManager
1177 tty8     01:11:24 Xorg
1183 ?        00:00:02 whoopsie
1329 ?        00:00:00 polkitd
1344 tty1     00:00:00 getty
1349 ?        00:00:03 wpa_supplicant
1350 ?        00:00:00 kdm
1447 ?        00:00:00 console-kit-dae
1520 ?        00:00:00 startkde
1574 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
1575 ?        00:00:06 gpg-agent
1578 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch
1579 ?        00:02:28 dbus-daemon
1613 ?        00:00:18 udisks-daemon
1614 ?        00:00:00 udisks-daemon
1645 ?        00:00:00 start_kdeinit
1646 ?        00:00:01 kdeinit4
1647 ?        00:00:02 klauncher
1649 ?        00:00:56 kded4
1654 ?        00:00:01 bluedevil-helpe
1656 ?        00:00:01 obex-data-serve
1659 ?        00:00:00 upowerd
1838 ?        00:00:02 kglobalaccel
1840 ?        00:00:02 kwalletd
1843 ?        00:00:01 kactivitymanage
1845 ?        00:00:00 kwrapper4
1846 ?        00:00:02 ksmserver
1849 ?        00:19:45 kwin
1857 ?        00:00:06 knotify4
1860 ?        00:35:52 plasma-desktop
1863 ?        00:00:01 kuiserver
1867 ?        00:02:12 ksysguardd
1874 ?        00:00:06 kaccess
1882 ?        00:00:13 nepomukserver
1883 ?        00:00:00 xsettings-kde
1889 ?        00:04:16 nepomukservices
1891 ?        00:00:35 krunner
1896 ?        00:28:18 pulseaudio
1898 ?        00:00:01 rtkit-daemon
1904 ?        00:00:01 akonaditray
1906 ?        00:00:35 nepomukcontroll
1911 ?        00:18:48 virtuoso-t
1912 ?        00:00:11 kmix
1914 ?        00:00:00 gconf-helper
1916 ?        00:00:00 gconfd-2
1929 ?        00:00:02 zeitgeist-datah
1930 ?        00:00:02 deja-dup-monito
1940 ?        00:00:03 python
1946 ?        00:00:01 polkit-kde-auth
1947 ?        00:00:04 klipper
1956 ?        00:00:05 zeitgeist-daemo
1964 ?        00:00:06 zeitgeist-fts
1973 ?        00:00:01 gvfsd
1974 ?        00:00:00 cat
1987 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gdu-volume
1991 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-fuse-daemo
1997 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-afc-volume
2002 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
2046 ?        00:00:01 ubuntuone-syncd
2084 ?        00:00:01 gnome-keyring-d
2091 ?        00:00:00 nepomukservices
2092 ?        00:01:21 nepomukservices
2093 ?        00:00:01 nepomukservices
2094 ?        00:02:58 nepomukservices
2145 ?        00:00:00 dconf-service
2151 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-metadata
8161 ?        00:00:00 kio_http_cache_
9088 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u:2H
10996 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch
10997 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
11002 ?        00:00:00 kdeinit4
11005 ?        00:00:00 klauncher
11008 ?        00:00:04 kded4
11327 ?        00:00:02 knotify4
11331 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd
11333 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-fuse-daemo
24083 ?        00:00:00 gnome-screensav
27181 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-trash
27773 ?        00:00:00 at-spi-bus-laun
30775 ?        00:00:00 update-apt-xapi
30793 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-http
31489 ?        00:01:54 kworker/1:1
32415 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:0
32416 ?        00:00:00 hci0
32417 ?        00:00:00 hci0
32420 ?        00:00:00 udevd
32421 ?        00:00:00 udevd
32427 ?        00:00:00 bluedevil-monol
32430 ?        00:00:00 dhclient
32433 ?        00:00:00 dnsmasq
```

Answer (score 1):

Procces-ID or PID are controlled by linux. You can't control or specify the PID in your programs. If you want to know the max number of processes on your system. You could do this:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

More info about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier).